# Weird error in Hadoop reducer

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

The reducer in my map-reduce job is as follows:

```
    public static class Reduce_Phase2 extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<IntWritable, Neighbourhood, Text,Text> {

    public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterator<Neighbourhood> values, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {

        ArrayList<Neighbourhood> cachedValues = new ArrayList<Neighbourhood>();

        while(values.hasNext()){                
            Neighbourhood n = values.next();                
            cachedValues.add(n);    
            //correct output
            //output.collect(new Text(n.source), new Text(n.neighbours));
        }

        for(Neighbourhood node:cachedValues){
            //wrong output               
            output.collect(new Text(key.toString()), new Text(node.source+"\t\t"+node.neighbours));
        }           
    }       
}
```

The`Neighbourhood` class has two attributes, `source` and `neighbours`, both of type `Text`. This reducer receives one key which has 19 values(of type `Neighbourhood`) assigned. When I output the `source` and `neighbours` inside the while loop, I get the actual values of 19 different values. However, if I output them after the while loop as shown in the code, I get 19 similar values. That is, one object gets output 19 times! It is very weired that what happens. Is there any idea on that?

Here is the code of the class `Neighbourhood`

```
   public class Neighbourhood extends Configured implements WritableComparable<Neighbourhood> {

    Text source ;
    Text neighbours ;

    public Neighbourhood(){
        source = new Text();
        neighbours = new Text();
    }

    public Neighbourhood (String s, String n){
        source = new Text(s);
        neighbours = new Text(n);
    }

    @Override
    public void readFields(DataInput arg0) throws IOException {

        source.readFields(arg0);
        neighbours.readFields(arg0);

    }

    @Override
    public void write(DataOutput arg0) throws IOException {

        source.write(arg0);
        neighbours.write(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Neighbourhood o) {         
        return 0;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're being caught out by a efficiency mechanism employed by Hadoop - Object reuse.

Your calls to `values.next()` is returning the same object reference each time, all Hadoop is doing behind the scenes is replaced the contents of that same object with the underlying bytes (deserialized using the `readFields()` method).

To avoid this you'll need to create deep copies of the object returned from `values.next()` - Hadoop actually has a utility class to do this for you called `ReflectionUtils.copy`. A simple fix would be as follows:

```
while(values.hasNext()){                
    Neighbourhood n = ReflectionUtils.newInstance(Neighbourhood.class, conf);
    ReflectionUtils.copy(values.next(), n, conf);
```

You'll need to cache a version of the job Configuration (conf in the above code), which you can obtain by overriding the `configure(JobConf)` method in your Reducer:

```
@Override
protected void configure(JobConf job) {
    conf = job;
}
```

Be warned though - accumulating a list in this way is often the cause of memory problems in your job, especially if you have 100,000+ values for a given single key.

Comment: Thanks @Chris. How can I override the configure method in the reducer? Besides, do you have a better solution than accumulating a list in order not to cause a memory problem?

Comment: updated with configure method example. What does your reducer do? At the moment you don't need to accumulate the values into a list - you should just be able to move the logic from that second loop into the first

Comment: Thanks @Chris. It solved the problem.
In the reducer, I need to output the key  (and its corresponding values) provided that the key has more than a certain number of values (let's say 100). So, I need to count the number of values and if its smaller than a predefined number, output them. Is there a better solution than accumulating them?

Comment: You'll need to accumulate the values into a collection of some sort to assert that you have more than 100 - but to avoid memory problems once the list reaches 101 you should output the ones accumulated and then write the remaining values left in the Iterator to the output